# Datadog check for autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, datadog

Iam in the process of writing a datadog check to trigger an alert for autoscaling groups when the number of running instances reaches the maximum value set in the auto scaling group.

This is pretty straightforward as I have done here

avg:aws.autoscaling.group_max_size by {autoscaling_group} - avg:aws.autoscaling.group_desired_capacity by {autoscaling_group} == 0

The problem that Iam facing is that this alert should only be triggered if the max value and min value are not equal.

I have trouble integrating this to the query..does anyone have any advice on how to integrate this to the query that ive written

Comment: Maybe create 2 separate monitors; one for your current query, and one that compares the values, then a composite monitor https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/create/types/composite/ to alarm on the results of both

Comment: this wouldnt be the solution as the second check should have the auto scaling groups which pass the first check and not the ones which have triggered the alert

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar by taking the number of in service instances and the max size, the setting a warning and alert threshold.

I noticed the query above didn't include a region after the autoscaling properties, either as a wildcard or explicitly written out. Maybe adding a {*} as below will help.

The metric queries are:

```
sum:aws.autoscaling.group_in_service_instances{*} by {autoscaling_group}
sum:aws.autoscaling.group_max_size{*} by {autoscaling_group}
a / b * 100
```

or

`sum:aws.autoscaling.group_in_service_instances{region:us-east-1} by {autoscaling_group} / sum:aws.autoscaling.group_max_size{region:us-east-1} by {autoscaling_group} * 100`

I then have a threshold limit of 90% to send a warning message, and 100% to send an alarm that it's maxed out.